# Instantiate class within parameter list when pointer is required

Tags: c++

I have a function:

```
void func(Obj* obj){
...
}
```

For convenience, I'd sometimes prefer to call it like

```
func(&MyObj(param1, param2));
```

That won't work of course since the object would be an rvalue. But how could I achieve what I try to do?

Comment: `template<typename T>
    T& lvalue(T&& x) {
        return x;
    } func(&lvalue(MyObj(param1, param2));`

Comment: @0x499602D2, can you convert that to an answer, with a bit of explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do:

```
Obj p(param1, param2);
func(&p);
```

Or, if and **only if** `func` manages the lifetime of its argument (otherwise, this is a memory leak), you could do:

```
func(new Obj(param1, param2));
```

Or rewrite `func()` to take a `Obj` instead of a `Obj*`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Obj myobject(param1, param2);
func(&myobject);
```

That will create the object on the stack and pass a pointer to it to the function `func`

Comment: Perhaps get `func` to use references.